# Move d3 circles away from center circle - force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on d3 to represent nodes in circles, when the size of a circle is changed then the circles around them should move away from the one's size got changed from being overlapped.

[image]

Consider the red circle above, when its size get changed then the others should move in the green arrow's direction. I tried with force simulation but I'm not able to achieve it and added the code below, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can somebody help please?

https://jsfiddle.net/m6s8dk7o/29/

```js
var w = 900,
  h = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RED1',
    size: 20,
    color: 'red'
  },{
    label: 'RAD2',
    size: 20,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL3',
    size: 20,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN4',
    size: 10,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO5',
    size: 40,
    color: '#b4975a'
  },{
    label: 'RAD6',
    size: 40,
    color: '#c99700'
  },{
    label: 'BIL7',
    size: 30,
    color: '#008ce6'
  },  {
    label: 'INO8',
    size: 30,
    color: '#b4975a'
  },{
    label: 'INO9',
    size: 40,
    color: '#b4975a'
  },{
    label: 'RAD10',
    size: 40,
    color: '#c99700'
  },{
    label: 'BIL11',
    size: 30,
    color: '#008ce6'
  },  {
    label: 'INO12',
    size: 30,
    color: '#b4975a'
  } ]
};

var add = function(){
 data.children[0].size = 80;
  render();
}
var reset = function(){
 data.children[0].size = 20;
  render();
}
var render = function(){

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size + 20
  }))

  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();
console.log(data)


      
let nodeLevel1 = svg.selectAll('circle')
                .data(data.children, (d) => {
                    // Attaching key for uniqueness
                    console.log(d)
                    return d.label;
                });
                
                nodeLevel1.exit().remove();
    let nodeLevel1Enter = nodeLevel1
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.size
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      
      nodeLevel1Enter = nodeLevel1Enter
                .merge(nodeLevel1)
                
      let level1CirclesUpdate = nodeLevel1Enter
               //.selectAll('circle')
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.size
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      
      
  }
  d3.select('#updatesize').on('click',function(){
  add();
  })
  d3.select('#resetsize').on('click',function(){
  reset();
  })
  render();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<a href='javascript:;' id='updatesize'>
Update red resource size
</a>  | 
<a href='javascript:;' id='resetsize'>
Reset red resource size
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not following your question: no circle is being overlapped, the `collide` is being updated with the correct radii.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes the circles are not overlapped but when a circle size increases the other circles around them is not moving in the same degree. In the example above, the circles move in different degree when red circle size is increased.

Comment: What are *different degrees*? The force is simply moving them according to `d.size + 20`, as you specified in the code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado when the size of middle circle is increased the other circles are randomly placed around that circle, the position of other circles were jumped from one point to another where its hard to track when there are lot of circles. The circles go away in a straight line from the center point.

Comment: They are randomly placed around again for a very simple reason: you're creating a new simulation every time. Just change the existing simulation, do not create a new one.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you for your help, a simple code example would help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172557/discussion-between-navin-leon-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: Sorry, I have no available time to chat. This is what I meant by using the same simulation: https://jsfiddle.net/gx8q6ybd/. That's just for you to get the idea.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado this is perfect! and thank you for your valuable time. I updated the code with transition https://jsfiddle.net/gx8q6ybd/8/. However, when I click reset, the other circles are not going back to its older position. any idea?

Comment: Please post this as a new question. As I said, that's **not** an working answer, it's just a demo for you to have an idea.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado got it thank you for the effort.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gx8q6ybd/39/ .  Please add your post as answer, so that I can mark it as answer.

Comment: No worries, feel free to write the answer yourself, then you can even accept it (after 48h).

Comment: _However, when I click reset, the other circles are not going back to its older position_
—
You just need to reset the simulation `alpha` using `simulation.alpha(1)`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For answer, the code is updated here jsfiddle.net/gx8q6ybd/39